# Always show mute button on items in REAPER

Tags: reaper

I'm using REAPER 3.76 and am muting and unmuting various items for comping purposes. There is a convenient mute button that appears on muted items to allow you to unmute them, but I would like it to stay there so I can re-mute them with a single click. Is that option available? I'm sure I saw a screenshot of someone with the mute button (and a few more) on all their clips.

[image: muted and unmuted clips]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Open the preferences pane.
-click on "Media" under the "Appearance" heading in the left hand menu.
-check both boxes for "muted" and "unmuted" in the middle of the panel.
-click "apply".

now you should see a mute button both when the item is muted and when it is unmuted.

be aware, the buttons will disappear when the the view is zoomed out very far anyway, but should be visible under most circumstances.

Comment: brilliant - I searched the preferences box for ages looking for that setting

Comment: to be honest the preferences box in Reaper is a pain. Items seem to be labeled in a strange way that doesn't really reveal what they actually do. If you're stuck looking for something you can type a word into the "Search" box in the lower left corner of the Preferences box, sometimes it gets you where you need to be, sometimes not.